# How can I sort subarray by key?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I Have array like this.

```
[PT. Bersinar Terang] => Array
(
    [2017] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [nama_perusahaan] => PT. Bersinar Terang
        )
    )

    [2016] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16
            [nama_perusahaan] => PT. Bersinar Terang
        )
    )
)
```

How can I sort ascending by years?
Thanks For help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ksort`. Here is the code.

```
ksort($arr['PT. Bersinar Terang']);
```

For more information, check this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php).

Answer (score 0):

Use [ksort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) function

```
ksort($arr['PT. Bersinar Terang']);
print_r($arr);exit;
```

[DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/2vvs-8r3p)

Comment: sorry when I try the result is bool(true), because [PT. Bersinar Terang] inside array. like this, `Array
(
    [PT. Mayora Indah Tbk] => Array
        (
            [2015] => Array
                ()

            [2017] => Array
                ()

        )

    [PT. GPP] => Array
        (
            [2016] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
`

Comment: Have you checked the demo?

Comment: Yes I was checked demo and my expectation result like that. But I have array structur like my comment on the top..